# Why my Makefile don't remove the intermediate files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying GNU make for a little text processing.

```
plotsource: memo.md
    split memo.md -l8
    cat xac | awk '/[0-9].*/{print $$1" "$$6}' > heapsort
    cat xab | awk '/[0-9].*/{print $$1" "$$6}' > downheat
    cat xaa | awk '/[0-9].*/{print $$1" "$$6}' > upheat
    join upheat downheat | join - heapsort > plotsource
```

I expected the intermediate files, xac, heapsort and so on, will be removed but it was there even after execution.

Why it live? How can I set up to delete them after the `plotsource` is created?

I tried @reinierpost 's answer but it also doesn't delete them.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuhmE.png)

Comment: Why not just add one more line after `join ... > plotsource` where you execute `rm -f heapsort downheat upheat`?

Comment: Well, I can add a line like that but before that, I want to know why it doesn't delete them automatically like object files.

Comment: Why would it delete them automatically?  If you think make will delete .obj files automatically just call the files heapshort.obj downheat.obj and upheat.obj.  Usually one has to create a 'clean' target. here's an interest blog: https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2009/10/10/gnu-make-and-deleting-intermediate-files.html

Comment: You haven't given any information to make about those files, they exist only in the context of the recipe, which make blindly passes to the shell - make has no idea you're creating `heapsort` or `downheat`, let alone that they're intermediate and should be deleted.

Comment: And to answer your last question, you can set up to delete them by adding a new command line `rm -f downheat upheat heapsort` at the end of your recipe.

Answer (score 1):

As [@red-cricket's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871740/why-my-makefile-dont-remove-the-intermediate-files/50205372#comment86759638_49871740), it seems that only the files of special types will be removed automatically.

The `.INTERMEDIATE` flag can specify a random file as intermediates explicitly.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As user657267 says, to make this happen, explain to  `make` that these are intermediate files.

```
plotsource: memo.md

xac xab xaa: memo.md
      split $< -l8

heapsort: xaa
    awk '/[0-9].*/{print $$1" "$$6}' $< > $@

downheat: xab
    awk '/[0-9].*/{print $$1" "$$6}' $< > $@

upheat: xac
    awk '/[0-9].*/{print $$1" "$$6}' $< > $@

plotsource: upheat downbeat heapsort
    join upheat downheat | join - heapsort > $@
```

Comment: No, it doesn't delete the intermediate files in my environment.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuhmE.png)